# Creating a generic / abstract "DBContext" Class for shared functionality among different DBs

Tags: c#, database, generics, inheritance, abstract-class

I am working on a C# project that is pulling data from `SQL Server`, `ODBC data-sources` and `Oracle Databases` at different times.

At this point, I have created 3 different classes - Once for each type of DB access. However, I am seeing that 95% of the code is identical between each of the libraries - The main difference being in creating the `Connection` and `Command` objects.

As a VERY simple example of what's in the classes, here could be an example:

```
public class Oracle
{
    static DataTable exec_DT(string query, string conn_str)
    {
        DataTable retVal = new DataTable();

        using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(conn_str))
            using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (OracleDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    retVal.Load(rdr);
                    rdr.Close();
                }
            }

        return retVal;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class SQLServer
{
    static DataTable exec_DT(string query, string conn_str)
    {
        DataTable retVal = new DataTable();

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conn_str))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                retVal.Load(rdr);
                rdr.Close();
            }
        }

        return retVal;
    }
}
```

Basically, I need to get the same kind of return data frmo each of my databases and the methods to do so are near-identical, the difference being the `Connection` and `Command`-type objects.

Now, when I look at both connection objects, I see that they both inherit from `DbConnection`:

```
public sealed class SqlConnection : DbConnection, ICloneable

public sealed class OracleConnection : DbConnection, ICloneable
```

But I still can't think of a good way to create a generic / abstract parent class that can stop the need for this kind of code duplication as the DBConnection / DBCommand classes are abstract and, when I try something along the following lines:

```
using (DbConnection conn = new DbConnection(conn_str))
using (DbCommand cmd = new DbCommand(query, conn))
```

I get errors such as `Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'System.Data.Common.DbCommand'`

I'm very much a newbie and any help / sample code / links to ways this has been done well in the past would really be **greatly** appreciated!

THANKS!!!

Comment: This might not apply to you directly -- it sounds like you have already made a design decision and have started implementation -- but if needing ADO.NET with support for being database agnostic then the patterns & practices [Data Access Application Block](http://daab.codeplex.com/) might be worth a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is to step back and think about the problem from another angle. You are duplicating lots of code because you are creating instances of the database and command classes within the method. So inject them instead:

```
public class SomeDBClass
{
    static DataTable exec_DT(DBConnection conn, DBCommand cmd)
    {
        DataTable retVal = new DataTable();
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            retVal.Load(rdr);
            rdr.Close();
        }
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

This approach has the added value that you can then test `exec_DT` without the need for either SQLServer or Oracle, by creating mock `DBConnection` and `DBCommand` that you then inject into your test cases.

Comment: Can't accept the answer yet, but that really does make perfect sense!!

Comment: Just a note: `DBConnection` and `DBCommand` should be `DbConnection` and `DbCommand`. And there is still a `SqlDataReader` that would need to be replaced to a `DbDatareader`

Answer (score 1):

I like [David's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30982431/15498). In the alternative, if you do still want to be creating connections and commands from within your shared code, what you could do is pass a [`DbProviderFactory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbproviderfactory(v=vs.110).aspx) instance to the constructor of your "DB Context" class.

You can then call e.g. `CreateCommand`, `CreateConnection` or whatever else you need to create, within each method.

Answer (score 0):

The [`DbProviderFactory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbproviderfactory(v=vs.110).aspx) class does exactly what you're looking for.

```
static DataTable exec_DT(string query, string conn_str)
{
    DataTable retVal = new DataTable();

    using (DbConnection conn = MyDbProvider.CreateConnection())
    {
        conn.ConnectionString = conn_str;

        using (DbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            conn.Open();

            using (DbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                retVal.Load(rdr);
                rdr.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

You can even use the [`DbProviderFactories`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbproviderfactories(v=vs.110).aspx) class to create a factory instance from the connection string in the config file.

```
DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(WebConfigurationManager
    .ConnectionStrings[name].ProviderName);
```